# Gradle build, solve dependency for library AAR stored on gitlab

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, gitlab, aar

I'm working on an android application and I need to reuse some modules (like navigation, header) in other android applications. My apps and modules are stored on gitlab, each of them has a repository.

What i would like to do if possible:

- store AAR library on gitlab
- use the url of the repository which contains all the libraries as a maven repository, and call this URL with gradle
- get a specific library from this URL (the module header, for example) by using a name, version...

I have some little ideas about how to call the repository URL, but I don't know how to create a reference to a specific module with a specific version...

Comment: i precise that i won't store the libraries locally, i won't use a local folder

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your questions, but I think you're asking about how to handle _dependencies_ in gradle. If that's the case, you should start by reading this tutorial. It will tell you how to let Gradle fetch dependencies from a remote Maven repo. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Comment: i know how to declare dependences to libraries on maven or jcenter repositories. But what about i'm not sure, is how to call an android module, which has to be stored on my gitlab repository. It can't be anywhere else for the need of the project.

Comment: Sorry I think there no maven repo support (yet); I've resolved to rebuild all the dependencies in .gitlab-ci.yml